# Terraform 0.12: Provider produced inconsistent final plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform configuration which creates an `aws_api_gateway_usage_plan` resource, using a computed value during the apply stage from a `local_file` resource.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "api_plan" {
  name         = var.usage_plan_name

  api_stages {
    api_id = jsondecode(file("dev.json")).resources[1].rest_api_id
    stage  = "api"
  }

  # Have to wait for the API to be created before we can create the usage plan
  depends_on = [local_file.chalice_config]
}
```

As you can see, I read `dev.json` to determine the `api_id` Terraform needs. The problem is that when I run `terraform apply`, the new safety checks described [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/terraform-0.12-compatibility.html#inaccurate-plans) notice that the previous value that `api_id` evaluated to has changed!

```
Provider produced inconsistent final plan: When expanding the plan for aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.api_plan
to include new values learned so far during apply, provider "aws" produced an invalid new value 
for .api_stages[0].api_id: was cty.StringVal("****"), but now cty.StringVal("****").
```

As that documentation describes, the correct way to solve this error is to specify that during the `plan` phase this `api_id` actually has yet to be `computed`. The problem is I'm not sure how to do this through a Terraform config - the documentation I've referenced is for the writers of the actual Terraform providers.

Looking at issues on GitHub, it seems like setting the initial value to `null` isn't a reasonable way to do this.

Any ideas? I am considering downgrading to Terraform 0.11 to get around this new safety check, but I was hoping this would be possible in 0.12.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible that there is a race condition with something (someone?) else modifying this resource?

Comment: Is this with a recent version of the AWS provider?

Comment: As the error message suggests, the main remedy when you encounter this error is to open a bug report in the issue tracker for the provider in question. In this case the bug could either be in the `aws_api_gateway_usage_plan` resource type (and thus the AWS provider) or in whatever resource type is producing the data in your `dev.json` file.

Comment: Is there a reason you are passing the rest API ID via a file instead of interpolating with the output from the rest API data source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/api_gateway_rest_api.html or even the resource if it's being created at the same time as the API gateway?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes, it is because I am not using the `api_gateway_rest_api` resource to create the API - I'm using another service which is launched through the same terraform script

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after thinking for a while I came up with a silly workaround that enabled me to "trick" Terraform into believing that the value for the `api_id` was to be computed during the `apply` phase, thereby disregarding the safety check.

What I did was replace the `api_id` expression with the following:

```
api_id = replace("=${aws_security_group.sg.vpc_id}=${jsondecode(file("files/handler/.chalice/deployed/dev.json")).resources[1].rest_api_id}", "=${aws_security_group.sg.vpc_id}=", "")
```

Essentially what I am doing is saying that the `api_id`'s value depends on a computed variable - namely, the `vpc_id` of a `aws_security_group` I create named `sg`. In doing so, Terraform recognizes this value is to be computed later, so the safety check is ignored.

Obviously, I don't actually want to have the `vpc_id` in here, so I used Terraform's string functions to remove it from the final expression.

This is a pretty hacky workaround, and I'm open to a better solution - just thought I'd share what I have now in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while creating lambda event source mapping. I overcome from it running
`terraform plan`
and then
`terraform apply`

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure how :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error when encoded my `user_data` scripts (with `filebase64` or `base64encode`) in places where I add to just simply use `file` or `templatefile` :

```
  user_data = file("${path.module}/provisioning_scripts/init_script.sh")

  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/provisioning_scripts/init_script.tpl", {
    USER  = "my-user"
    GROUP = "my-group"
  })
```

(*) I can't 100% reproduce it but I'm adding this solution as another possible reason for receiving the mentioned error.

---

Read also in [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10297).